# Python logging module platform differences: OSX vs. Linux

Tags: python, logging, cross-platform

Can anyone help me understand why python's logging module creates a StreamHandler on import, but only on some distributions?  weird.. (note: happens on any python3)

On Mac

```
Python 3.5.6 (default, Dec 19 2019, 14:59:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger().handlers
[<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x108fc2630>]
```

Linux:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jan  3 2020, 19:27:19)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger().handlers
[]
>>>
```

I can't seem to find any explanation about this behavior difference!

EDIT:

A bit more investigation suggests that some module installed in the `virtualenv` is causing this behavior mismatch. I created a fresh one with the same python interpreter and no handler gets made. I'm trying to investigate which module seems to cause this.

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I always get an empty list. It might be some site-customisation of your Python installation that's causing it. It's an old version of OS X, though - on an old box.

Comment: @VinaySajip thanks for taking the time to test this, you're right it was my environment / local install. It looks like the `vext` library is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't actually a platform difference, but was a result of an installed library.

I filed the issue upstream https://github.com/stuaxo/vext/issues/63